# wp query with dynamic taxonomies and terms?

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy, wp-query

I need wp_query with more than one taxonomies and terms which are dynamic. Multiple terms to one taxonomies each. Like If one taxonomy is **Color** it has terms **blue,green,red** Second taxonomy is **Size** and terms **7,8,9** this taxonomy is **Price** and its terms are **500$,600$** and so on.

I need to filter results based on checkboxes like happens on any e-commerce websites.Let's say first I select **blue** color then products are those which belong to **blue** then if I select **green** then products are those which belong to both **blue** and **green** but now if I select **7** then product will be those which belong to **blue,green having size 7** .

Hope you are getting what I need.I saw on codex for multiple taxonomy but it is having only 2 taxonomies which are static but in my case it is dynamic and can be more than 5.

In codex it is the code..

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'action', 'comedy' )
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'actor',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'action', 'comedy' )
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'actor',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

but what if i have more than 2 e.g 5(dynamic).

Please give me any solution.

I also write query intead of Wp-Query but not working it is adding result of blue,green with size 7 instead of filtering.

Here is query.

```
$taxonomy_name = "'" . implode("','", $taxonomy_name_ar) . "'";
$term_name = "'" . implode("','", $term_name_ar) . "'";

$querystr = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'product' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy in (".$taxonomy_name.")
    AND $wpdb->terms.slug in (".$term_name.")
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
    LIMIT 10
    ";
echo $querystr;
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

**Note** $tanomy_name is having the number of taxonomies like color,size,price and terms having number of terms like 7,8,blue,green

**UPDATE : AFTER ANSWER**

```
$tax_query = array( 'relation' => 'AND' );


foreach($taxonomy_array as $taxonomy_array_value){

$term_value_array = array();

foreach($term_array[$taxonomy_array_value] as $term_value){

        array_push($term_value_array,$term_value);
    }

$term_name = "'" . implode("','", $term_value_array) . "'";

        $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy_array_value,
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array($term_name)

    );


}
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => $tax_query
    );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one idea for a dynamic multiple taxonomy query:

```
// construct the tax-query: 
$tax_query = array( 'relation' => 'AND' );

// check if movie_genre taxonomy is to be included
if( $bMovieGenre ){
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array( 'action', 'comedy' )
    );
 }

// check if actor taxonomy is to be included
if( $bActor ){
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'actor',
        'field'    => 'id',
        'terms'    => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    );
 }

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => $tax_query,
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

where `$bActor` and `$bMovieGenre` are constructed from the user input.

In general, if your user input array is like:

```
$selected = array( 
    array( 'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre' , 
           'terms'    => array( 'action' , 'comedy') ,
           'field'    => 'slug' ,
           'operator' => 'IN' ,
    ),
    array( 'taxonomy' => 'actor' , 
           'terms'    => array( 103, 115, 206 ) ,
           'field'    => 'slug' ,
           'operator' => 'NOT IN' ,
    ),
);
```

then you can try this to construct the dynamic taxonomy query :

```
$tax_query = array( 'relation' => 'AND' );

foreach( $selected as $sel ){

    $tax_query[] = array( 
                      'taxonomy' => $sel['taxonomy'] , 
                      'terms'    => $sel['terms'] , 
                      'field'    => $sel['field'] ,
                      'operator' => $sel['operator'] ,
                   );
}
```

or just

```
$tax_query = array( 'relation' => 'AND' );

foreach( $selected as $sel ){

    $tax_query[] = $sel; 

}
```

Comment: you are checking two taxonomies and taking two variables of taxonomy while I have multiple taxonomies and also don't know there name also terms are also in multiple number and dynamic coming from ajax. e.g I have array of taxonomy and corressponding terms array

Comment: I am using your code and making it dynamic with terms but it works for once only means when taxanoy = colors and terms = 'red' but when taxonomy = colors and terms = 'red','green' then it's not working

Comment: In the above example `$tax_query[]` is constructed from the user input, you should be able to adjust it to your needs. I updated the answer where you construct `$selected` from the user input.

Comment: Your updated code might have a problem with `'terms'    => array($term_name),` try instead `'terms'    => $term_value_array`.